# Yii2 File Validation Error not working after set enableAjaxValidation to true

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Previously, when I set enableAjaxValidation to false on my ActiveForm , the file validation worked so well ,but after I set enabledAjaxValidation to true in order to check unique slug, it doesn't work.
Here is what I've done

```
Form:
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'] , 'enableAjaxValidation' => true,'id' => 'article-form']); ?>

 Model rule:
[['slug'], 'unique'],
[['featureFile' , 'bannerFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg' , 'on' => 'create'],
```

Controller:

```
use yii\web\Response; //Ajax Validation
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm; //Ajax Validation

 if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
 {
     Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
     return ActiveForm::validate($model);
 }
```

Even though I choose the image file already but it still show validation error
[image]

Please help!!!

Comment: Please read this : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6873

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the ajax validation of the specified field.

Try

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'featureFile', ['enableAjaxValidation' => false])->fileInput() ?>
```